# time out error calling xxx.cloudapp.net in windows azure's centos VM. Configured endpoints and installed apache, PHP

Tags: linux, apache, azure, virtual-machine, centos6

I have Centos running in Windows azure cloud. I have installed apache, PHP and configured endpoint as

`NAME PROTOCOL PUBLICPORT PRIVATEPORT LOAD-BALANCE DSET NAME

HTTP    TCP --------80   --------   80-----------------------------------------------

SSH TCP ---------22   -------- 22   -----------------------------------------

xml_rpc TCP ---8080  -------  8080           -`
 
When i point the browser to my

> dns.cloudapp.net or my PUBLIC VIP(Virtual IP)

i am getting timeout error.  i when i search about this, all i see is install lamp and configure endpoint, point your browser to xxx.cloudapp.net, and you should be able to see apache's test page. but its not happening.

kindly suggest me if anything i am missing.
Any help would be much appreciated.
thanks.

EDIT:This is what i got when i nmap- >

```
[root@xxxx ~]# nmap -sT -O localhost
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-02-03 11:42 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000054s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
631/tcp  open  ipp
1935/tcp open  rtmp
8021/tcp open  ftp-proxy
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```